# How to format the String "2016-03-23T11:23:11.305+01:00" with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, time, simpledateformat, parseexception

How can I convert the String `"2016-03-23T11:23:11.305+01:00"` into a date?

I already tried the following, but I get a ParseException.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> z =   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
>
> Z =   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
>
> X = Time zone ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
> Pattern letters are usually repeated, as their number determines the exact presentation:

you should define the `SimpleDateFormat` with a `X` for the timezone to represent it for the `ISO 8601` as.

```
String d = "2016-03-23T11:23:11.305+01:00";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date da = df.parse(d);
```

Also taken from the example in this doc

> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"  = 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00

Comment: Yes, and let's hope the OP is at least on Java-7, otherwise he/she will not benefit from pattern symbol X.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use only 1 `Z`: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");`

Comment: I tried it before, but it doesn't work.